# How do you calculate damage when no weapon or items are equipped?

Tags: diablo-iii

I'm trying to build yet another awesome calculator, and have run into an issue. I can't figure out the right way to calculate damage when no items are equipped?

All the calculators I've seen require a weapon (of course, duh, no one runs around with no items). However, in my app, when you have no items I want the correct damage to display, instead of nothing, or throwing an error.

This is the hero I'm using as an test dummy: http://us.battle.net/d3/en/profile/msuBREAKER-1374/hero/3955832

Comment: I don't get what you are trying to achieve. What damage do you want to display if you have no weapon equipped ?

Comment: This question is off-topic because it is about designing an app.

Comment: It is a question about damage calculation in D3, not app design. The damage I speak of is the one displayed when you have no items, see here: http://media.kshabazz.net/images/d3-screenshots/diablo-3-no-items-damage.PNG

Comment: Does it honestly matter? There is no reason to ever run around or try to kill something without a weapon.

Comment: I don't suppose you remember naked sorceress of D2 @Frank?

Comment: @Sorean D2 and D3 are dramatically different beasts.  Everything in D3 is based off of weapon DPS, so there is no reason at all to run around without one.  Investing so much time into a scenario that doesn't happen makes no sense.  Just plug zero into the formula and be done with it.

Comment: I understand they are different beasts, but just because someone is curious about a formula doesn't make it pointless.

Comment: I agree that it is pointless to run aounrd D3 with no gear. However there is one achievement where you have to survive beating Diablo with no gear. I've yet to do this. Also this serves as a base for getting better calculated results to help determine what is the best gear to choose. As we all know, D3 is all about numbers. There better the numbers the more fun you'll have.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe that some time ago, the damage for a 'punch' (attack without weapon) was stated in the tooltip, and that it was 1-4 damage.

This tooltip seems to have changed, but by reverse engineering the damage range still seems to be correct.

Looking at your monk's sheet, he has 217 mainstat, resulting in 8.12 dps.

Sheet DPS is calculated as follows:

`DPS = <avg damage> * (1 + <crithit> * <crit%> ) * (1 + <mainstat> / 100) * <atk/sec>`

Plugging in the known numbers:

`8.12 = <avg damage> * (1 + 0.5 * 0.05) * (1 + 217 / 100) * 1`

Gives us an `<avg damage>` of 2.49904 (Caused by rounding the DPS down to 2 decimals)

`2.5 * (1 + 0.5 * 0.05) * (1 + 217 / 100) * 1 = 8.123125 ~= 8.12`

If the default punch was indeed 1-4 damage, its average damage would be 2.5, so that fits.

Comment: Mad props, I tried to reverse engineer this and failed. Looking at what you wrote, I can see where I went wrong. I got the order of operation wrong when it came to calculating the mainStat factor, as I added 1 to 217 before dividing. So I had 2.18 where I should have had 3.17. So happy for your help. Thanks!